# Master Data Services 2019 - Derived Hierarchy issue

Tags: sql-server, excel, master-data-services

I've been facing an issue with a Master Data Services (MDS) derived hierarchies. At first the hierarchy worked fine but after some time (do not know how long) I am not able to load the MDS data via Excel with MDS 2019 Add-in. I am receiving an error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC". If an attribute which is filtered by the derived hierarchy is excluded from the load, the data is loaded just fine.
I believe that that the issue will not be related to MDS since it's working fine via Web Application. Moreover, two of my colleagues does not have this issue.
I know that the error code is related to "NAME_NOT_FOUND" but I do not use any explicit formulas starting with "=". So I believe that Excel is not able to find some function/object of the MDS Add-in.

I tried to reinstall the whole Office 365 and MDS Add-in for Excel but the issue still persists. I've also compare app versions with my colleagues and the versions are the same.
I also tried to disable the error checking for formulas within Excel options: Options-->Formulas with no success.

**App versions:**

- Microsoft SQL Server 2019 MDS Add-in for Excel 15.0.2000.5
- Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2110 Build 16.0.14527.20234) 64-bit
- MDS database located on Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU17) (KB5001092) - 13.0.5888.11 (X64) Enterprise - Server A
- MDS 2019 service - Server B

**Results from tracing:**

```
MDS Warning and Error tracing on the server:
Time,CorrelationId,Operation,Level,Message
11/11/2021 16:42:18,00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,Unknown,Start,"Service started successfully, Assembly version: 15.0.0.0, file version: 15.0.4178.1"
11/11/2021 16:42:18,00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,Unknown,Error,"ApiContractVersion: 8000"
```

**Excel Add-in MDS log:**

```
2021-11-11T16:19:37.269       28856 EXCEL.EXE                      EXCEL.EXE                                Generic          EventType: Error, Message: DataView.DoOperationAsync failed. Exception: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.MasterDataServices.ExcelAddInCore.DataView.<>c__DisplayClass84_0.<LoadData>b__4(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)'
2021-11-11T16:19:37.270       28856 EXCEL.EXE                      EXCEL.EXE                                Generic          EventType: Error, Message: DataView.LoadData failed. Exception: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.MasterDataServices.ExcelAddInCore.DataView.<>c__DisplayClass84_0.<LoadData>b__4(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)'.
2021-11-11T16:19:37.356        2444 EXCEL.EXE                      EXCEL.EXE                                Generic          EventType: Error, Message: ExceptionMessageBoxShown@Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
2021-11-11T16:19:37.356        2444 Unknown                        Unknown                                  Generic          EventType: Information, Message: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.MasterDataServices.ExcelAddInCore.DataView.<>c__DisplayClass84_0.<LoadData>b__4(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
2021-11-11T16:19:38.724        2444 EXCEL.EXE                      EXCEL.EXE                                Generic          EventType: Information, Message: ExceptionMessageBoxClosed@Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
2021-11-11T16:19:40.343       28856 EXCEL.EXE                      EXCEL.EXE                                Generic          EventType: Information, Message: Operation BeginInternalLoadData ended at: 11/11/2021 16:19:40. Duration = 00:00:03.8691037
```

I would be grateful for your opinion and potential solution.